# Ruby backslash escaping: ' \\ \hline' as string

Tags: ruby, string, escaping

I'm trying to simply have the string

```
 '\\ \hline'
```

in my program.
Now I used single quotes so I expect

```
 a = ' \\ \hline'
```

to give me what I want, instead I get

```
 irb(main):001:0> a = ' \\ \hline'
 => " \\ \\hline"
```

How would I go about getting what I want, seeing as I have no idea on the unexpected second double backslash?

edit: similarly with `a = "\"`

Comment: no, this gives me the literal 6 backslasches (yes I'm also having much trouble conveying my backslashes here)

Comment: Oh my god, I was using `pp`, thank you, that was silly and very confusing!

Comment: You need to use double backticks to escape correctly in SO comments: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190395

Comment: Type `gets.chomp` in IRB, enter `\\ \hline` and press return. The output will be the correctly escaped string literal, i.e. `"\\\\ \\hline"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to escape all the backslashes:

```
str = "\\\\ \\hline"
puts str
# => \\ \hline
```

please notice that it also works if you use single quotes string and escape only the single backslashes:

```
str = '\\\\ \hline'
puts str
# => \\ \hline
```

and also if your backslash precedes something that may look like a char that can be escaped:

```
str = '\\\\ \nline'
puts str
# => \\ \nline
```

but this is not true if you use double quotes:

```
str = "\\\\ \nline"
puts str
# => \\ 
# => line
```

The escaping of **all** backslashes is not mandatory (as @mudasobwa correctly pointed out) and there are cases in which you may decide to not use it, but IMHO it is preferable, in particular if you use strings with double quotes.

Comment: “You have to escape all the backslashes” is technically wrong. One needs to escape only those backslashes that have the meaning. `\h` might be not escaped, it’ll still be working fine. Try `puts '\\\\ \hline'`.

Comment: `\h` maybe not, but if it is `\n`? `\\h` is not required, but I prefer to suggest something that works also in special cases...

Comment: Yes, that’s why I used “technically wrong” wording.

Comment: @mudasobwa I think it is better to include your point in the answer, to make it more complete...