# Cannot install Ruby Gem on Window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I installed the latest Ruby with DevKit (version 3.2.3) on a Windows 11 machine (always up to date). However, I failed to install Rails with the following message (at the bottom). It seems the core part is this

> make failedNo such file or directory - C:GnuWin32binmake.exe

I have "make" path at "C:\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe". It looks like "" was trimmed away.

```
PS C:\Users\thaia> gem install rails
Using rubygems directory: C:/Users/thaia/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/Users/thaia/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/io-console-0.7.2/ext/io/console
C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_io_path()... no
checking for rb_io_descriptor()... yes
checking for rb_io_get_write_io()... yes
checking for rb_io_closed_p()... no
checking for rb_io_open_descriptor()... no
checking for HAVE_RUBY_FIBER_SCHEDULER_H... yes

creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Users/thaia/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/io-console-0.7.2/ext/io/console
C:GnuWin32binmake.exe DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20240329-13216-3yunzy sitelibdir\=./.gem.20240329-13216-3yunzy clean
current directory: C:/Users/thaia/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/io-console-0.7.2/ext/io/console
C:GnuWin32binmake.exe DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20240329-13216-3yunzy sitelibdir\=./.gem.20240329-13216-3yunzy

make failedNo such file or directory - C:GnuWin32binmake.exe

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/thaia/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/io-console-0.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/thaia/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/io-console-0.7.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking but you will need to use `"C:\\GnuWin32\\bin\\make.exe"`, `'C:\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe'`, or `"C:/GnuWin32/bin/make.exe"`. There are many posts about the need to escape backslashes in a double quoted string but [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50742198/1978251) is just one of those.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks. It fixed my issue :) I used "\\" in the path